# Sharing sessions between concrete5 and codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, concrete5

I have installed Concrete5 in `http://www.example.com/concrete5/` and Codeigniter in `http://www.example.com/codeigniter`. Is it possible to use the Concrete5 session in the Codeigniter directory? If this is possible, can someone give me a hint how to do it? Thanks.

***edit: additional information:***
They are on the same server, but in different folders :) Each works as it should. But now I need the user object of concrete5 in my codeigniter application.

Comment: Sorry :s but did not quite understand. Did you install concrete5 concrete5 folder, and the folder codeigniter codeigniter, you put both applications in the same folder? but when accessed the urls will get application folder x or y?

Comment: They are on the same server, but in different folders :) Each works as it should. But now I need the user object of concrete5 in my codeigniter application.

Comment: have you tried this? otherwise use cookies....

Comment: Why not just use cookies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharing sessions between these two isn't possible. In my opinion cookies should be the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create a wrapper / converter.

Luckily, it should be much easier to write this for codeigniter (to read concrete5) than concrete5 (to read codeigniter). But it won't be at all trivial.

James